# Allure report generation and display speed in case of large amount of tests and attachments

Tags: jenkins, pytest, allure

In our company we are using Pytest+Allure+Jenkins for CI and test automation.
With test quantity growing, we have met a problem with allure report generation speed.

When using Allure **v1.4.24.RC3**, for 208684 tests allure generation takes **23** minutes. Which is not acceptable, as report generation takes more time than test execution (13 min) and, sometimes, when server is overloaded generation can take up to 4 hours.

```
 > ls /app/install/pytest-results-2 | wc -l
 > 204414

 > ls /app/install/pytest-results-2/*.xml | wc -l
 > 271

 > time /media/sf_shared/tools/allure-commandline/bin/allure generate /app/install/pytest-results-2 -o /home/ci/allure_results-v1.4.24.RC3_only2
 > Report successfully generated to the directory </home/ci/allure_results-v1.4.24.RC3_only2>. Use `allure report open` command to show the report.
 > 
 > real    23m38.121s
 > user    13m43.380s
 > sys     9m54.877s
```

When using Allure **v2.3.1**, for 208684 tests allure generation takes **3** minutes. This could be ok, but with Allure v2.3.1 report opening in browser is extremely slow and often browser crashes and closes with error.

```
> time /media/sf_shared/tools/allure-2.3.1/bin/allure generate /app/install/pytest-results-2 -o /home/ci/allure_results-v2.3.1_only2
> Report successfully generated to /home/ci/allure_results-v2.3.1_only2
>
> real    3m22.951s
> user    2m44.551s
> sys     1m3.972s
```

Can anyone suggest how to improve report generation/display speed? Maybe some suggestions on how to use allure plugin in pytests?

Comment: The problem is that for such amount of tests json index that contains links to all the tests has a size about 1GB. So browser can't handle it. We can't do the pagination in the report for such case because of tree - the solution gonna be overcomplicated at this point. So the only way I can see to handle the problem - add an ability to hide all the passed tests from tabs (suites, behaviors, packages and timeline).  Is that acceptable for you?

Comment: Well, probably yes.
We are interested only in failed cases (for these tests). But how it will look like? Passed cases will be excluded in generation process?

Comment: Nope, they gonna be filtered from some tabs by default